# What is the recommended storage location for mapsforge map files?

Tags: android, mapsforge

I'm developing an Android app which uses [mapsforge](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapsforge) for displaying maps.

These vector map files can be rather big (several hundred MB) and they can be used by all Android apps using mapsforge (which is a really awesome piece of software BTW).

So I'd like to download the map-files to a location where other apps can access them as well.

If there was something like `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` with type = `MAPS`, I'd use it. But there's only MUSIC, RINGTONES, DCIM, DOWNLOADS and the like.

**So, where should we locate these shareable files?**

Is it possible to invent a new type like 'Maps' or 'MapsforgeMaps'?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about the security, `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` seems appropriate.

Another option that looks more secure could be [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Using the [getDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) is also a valid option I think. It creates the directory if it doesn't exist where application can store its own custom data files.

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question. What I need is a public directory where every app can read and write those shared map-files.

Comment: The option 1 and 3 I wrote are for pubilc directory itself. getDir() creates a public directory if it doesn't exist if you pass MODE_WORLD_READABLE or MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE. What I wanted to say is that you can create your own public directory.